# Is it possible to include the os library in lua 4.0?

Tags: datetime, lua, operating-system, lua-4.0

I'm stuck using the 4.0 version of lua which does not seem to support the os library. Is there a way to include this library into my project?
Or get another way to use the functionality contained within pertaining to date time calculations?

Preferably by using a *.lua file and not a *.c file since I don't have complete access to the code.

When I run the following line,

```
print(os.time{year=1970, month=1, day=1, hour=0})
```

I get an error stating:

> attempt to index global 'os'(a nil value)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you stuck with lua 4?

Comment: If you can't get what you need using [the Lua 4.0 standard libraries](http://www.lua.org/manual/4.0/manual.html#6.), then a `.lua` file cannot possibly replicate the `os` library; you'd need a C module.

Comment: @hjpotter92: I'm stuck with 4.0 because the application I'm running is made in 4.0 and is not mine to upgrade. I can however add lua functions.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo: I was afraid of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Colonel Thirty Two](https://stackoverflow.com/users/646619/colonel-thirty-two) said it's not possible to use the os library. So the time() funciton is not available for me.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the (totally correct) [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36058766/98528) (that if "os" access was not allowed to you, you're generally done), there's some *very slight* chance the Original Programmer may have provided you with some alternative facilities to do your thing *(fingers crossed)*. In a perfect world, those would be described in some kind of a User's Manual for your scripting environment. But if the manual was lost to time (or never existed in the first place), you might possibly try your luck at exploring any preloaded libraries by digging through the result of the [`globals()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/4.0/manual.html#globals) Basic Function. (At least I hope that's how it was done in 4.0 too.) That is, if the Original Programmer didn't block *globals()* for you too...